# Print specfic rows of a df to a txt file. Python incorrectly stacking each column into one?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, split

I'm trying to write data to 3 different text files based on the format of a column called "date" that is a string in the form of either mmmyyyy, qQyyyy, or yyyy (ex: JAN2018, 1Q2018, and 2018). So far I've tried taking the length of the date, and write to text files based on that, but my output comes out as every column for each date type stacked into one mega column. I'm also not sure how to preserve the columns headers when writing to new files for each date type. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's example (made up numbers for simplification, actual dates)

```
date        c1    c2    .....
jan2016    2.2   1.1
feb2016    2.5   2.2
mar2016    3.1   1.4
apr2016    2.2   1.5
jun2016    1.5   2.6
jul2016    4.3   2.2
1Q2016     2.8   4.1
2Q2016     1.3   3.8
2016       3.3   2.5



   for i, row in data.iterrows():
    sort = (data.iloc[i,0])
    s = len(sort)
    header = data.columns
    if s == 6:
        d = data.iloc[i,:]
        #header.to_csv(quarterly, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a') (this didnt work)
        #d.to_csv(quarterly, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
        np.savetxt(quarterly, d.values, fmt='%s')
```

I want 1 text file for month year, 1 for quarter year, and 1 for year

Comment: You could possibly `groupby` on the length of the string. Side note; I'm looking at this on a phone and it's a dense block of text. It looks like an interesting question, it might be better to summarise the text a bit.

Comment: it would be nice to have an example of data frame you are dealing with. The column your want to apply condition and few other.

Comment: I tried to add example data and shortened to clarify!